# EU Citizens: range settings of DJI Digital FPV system (FCC vs CE)?

Tags: first-person-view, range, dji, dji-air-unit

I'm looking to buy the DJI Digital FPV System and I'm now looking at the range. In [the specs](https://www.dji.com/nl/fpv/info) it says:

```
Max. Transmission Distance
FCC/SRRC: <4 km
CE: <0.7 km
MIC: <2.5km
```

I'm living in the EU, but I obviously would like the long range 4km version. So I was wondering; are these versions different in hardware, in software or is it simply a setting in the software? And if I buy this in the EU, could I switch it to the FCC version so that I could enjoy full range?

Is there anybody from the EU here that has the Digital FPV system and can tell more about it? Is there a menu setting for this? And what is your experience with the range?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is due to regulation - in the EU, the permitted radio power output is lower than that allowed under the FCC regulations, which results in reduced range.

Without a licence from your countries telecoms regulator, it would be illegal to operate the FCC equipment in Europe.

It is likely to be a software setting, but there might be hardware differences if the costs make business sense (possibly cheaper hardware Vs. different production process.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know of the legal difficulties, but I'm still wondering about it. Would you know how I would be able to find out?

Comment: I'm afraid that, as what you are trying to do appears to be illegal, it is out-of-scope for this site. If you think you have misrepresented your circumstances, feel free to edit the question. (However, I am not sufficiently familiar with the DJI FPV system to answer that part of the question anyway!)

Answer (score 1):

For people who find this in the future. It is possible: https://oscarliang.com/dji-fpv-system-fcc-700mw/

But remember; don't break the law!